# ASP.NET MVC - How to get Ajax 'onclick' for a specific action (I need for Ajax.ActionLink what Url.RouteUrl does for Html.ActionLink)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, url, actionlink

**REVISION**
**I want add a onclick to a  element that handles a Ajax request, not just a route-redirect.**

---

I have these options for a route-url.

```
Html.ActionLink(params)
Url.RouteUrl(params) 'returns JUST ActionUrl
```

So I can go like

```
<div onclick="javascript:location.href('<%=Url.RouteUrl(params)%>')"></div>
```

---

**But how do I generate the following??**

```
<div onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, updateTargetId: 'WorkorderDetails' });"></div>
```

Comment: pretty vague question, do you want to call an action in your controller using ajax or what?

Comment: yes, I tried to rephrase... How do I get just the onclick part that gets generated for a Ajax response... I don't want to be bound to a Anchor tag executing the ajax request...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that it is not possible. The Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick() function relies on the  anchor tag to function correctly. The href specified in the anchor is used to determine which service is called on the server.

I ended up creating a Ajax.ActionLink() and making it invisible (display:none). I know invoke the click using Javascript. jQuery actually (normal invoke: link.click() does not work properly!):

```
$(link).trigger("click");
```

Comment: +1 thankyou! I found your answer 2 years later and it helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question right, but you want just the raw URL, based upon an Action Method or something?

Then how about the [UrlHelper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx)?

This [previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366498/creating-urls-with-asp-net-mvc-and-routeurl) discusses this option.

Like I said, I'm not sure I understood the question 100%, though.